# Using an existing SQLite database in MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've created a SQLite database that contains records from some JSON using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated), and I want to use MagicalRecord to query it.

MagicalRecord sees the NSManagedObject (`BlogPost`) and can create records, but it doesn't see the prepopulated records, so I'm guessing it's not seeing the SQLite file I've added. I've verified that the SQLite database does indeed contain rows using a SQLite client.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, I've put:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"DBG.sqlite"];
```

And in `applicationWillTerminate:`:

```
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];
```

When I call `[BlogPost MR_findAll]` in a controller, it returns an empty set. DBG.sqlite is at the root of the project directory, and I've tried putting it in "Copy Bundle Resources", but `blogPosts` still returns an empty set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is you SQLite file connected to your Core Data model definition? How did you create it?

Comment: I created it using the tutorial linked in in the question. (Basically, I made a command line tool that uses the Core Data models in my main app (the app described in the question) to convert JSON into Core Data records, then copied the resulting SQLite file into my main app.) Am I incorrectly assuming that `setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:` is the way to connect Core Data to the existing datastore?

Comment: Did you change the model in any way since generating the sqlite file?

Comment: No, haven't touch it at all.

Comment: By default MR does a lot of logging so there should be some clue there if it's having an issue. Usually (in debug mode) if the sqlite file you supply doesn't match the data model version it will be deleted.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that looked useful in the log, but I'm also not terribly familiar with Core Data. I've put the debug log [here](http://pastebin.com/vyvUwNet), in case it's helpful.

Comment: Go to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator+MagicalRecord.m` and debug through `MR_addSqliteStoreNamed:withOptions:` checking for errors. Also, have you checked for other entities in the store?

Comment: Have you figured this out afterwards?  This is exactly what I'd like to do as well.  I created a utility app that takes xml document and dumps it into core data.  Now I want to prepopulate another app with the coredata/sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @Wain! The issue ended up not being MR-related (see the answer for details).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue ended up being that the preloaded SQLite db needs to be copied to the default path of the application's db:

```c
NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentPath = [paths lastObject];

NSURL *storeURL = [documentPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBG.sqlite"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
    NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DBG" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    NSError* err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Unable to copy preloaded database.");
    }
}
```

This should be placed just before `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"DBG.sqlite"];`.

Comment: The above solution didn't work for prefilled core data until I changed `setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed` to `setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed`