# Objective-c NSXMLParser with Coredata takes too long to parse and store data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsxmlparser, magicalrecord

I'm not a experience xcode/objective-c programmer so I'm sorry if you might not understand somethings I might say, or somethings I might say wrong.

So everything started with apple rejecting our app because it says:

"*Your app did not include sufficient content in the binary for the app to function at launch, and we were required to download or unpack additional resources before we could use it.*"

Because our app is a transports app, it needs to download dynamic data from services to keep the app with the most accurate and updated data. So basically everytime we open the app we ask the user to download the data (~2.5 MB), but since Apple refused to aprove the app I made an exception and let user enter without downloading any data, but it needs to convert the local XML file into core-data database.

My problem is, this file that is like 2,5 MB space with ~17k lines **takes at least 2 minutes** to read and store the provided data.

So I tried to see the parser if it was the problem but the code seems fine to me.

I know that this what I'm doing might not be the solution because of what Apple said the "*unpacking additional resources*" so I think it won't pass the app verification, but still I wanted this to do the parse and store with less time...

This is my code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    //    <Network LinesNumber="28" ZonesNumber="112" StopsNumber="114">
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Network"]) {
        int ln = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"LinesNumber"] intValue];
        int zn = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"ZonesNumber"] intValue];
        int sn = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"StopsNumber"] intValue];
        totalItems = (totalItems + ln + sn + zn) *1.0;
        updateaction(0);
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Stop"]) {
        int idStop = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
        NSString* name = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Name"] capitalizedString];
        NSString* codName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"CodName"];
        int idZona = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IdZona"] intValue];
        int idDistrito = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IdCounty"] intValue];
        int idConcelho = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IdDistrict"] intValue];
        int idFreguesia = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IdParish"] intValue];
        double latitude = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoordYY"] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoordXX"] doubleValue];
        NSString* obs = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Observation"];

        OperatorZone *zone = [Database operatorZoneFromId:idZona];

        Stop *stop = [Database createStop:idStop withName:name withCodName:codName withIdZona:idZona withIdDistrito:idDistrito withIdConcelho:idConcelho withIdFreguesia:idFreguesia withLatitude:latitude withLongitude:longitude withObservations:obs withOperatorZone:zone];
        [stop setCicID:cicID];
        [stop setOperatorID:operatorID];
        NSLog(@"Saving stop with Name: %@, cicID: %@, operatorID: %@", name, cicID, operatorID);

        [stops_dict setObject:stop forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:idStop]];

        if (zone != nil) {
            [zone addStopsObject:stop];
          //  [[zone managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]; // TIRAR ISTO DAQUI E POR NO FIM DE TUDO
        }

        itemcount++;
        progress = itemcount/totalItems;
        updateaction(progress);
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Line"]) {
//        NSLog(@"Checking line..");
        int sid = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
        NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"LineName"];
        NSString * returnName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ReturnLineName"];
        NSString * companyID = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"CompanyId"];
        int isCircular = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IsCircular"] boolValue];
        int idOperator = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"IdOperator"] intValue];
        NSString * version = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Version"];
        currentLine = [Database createLine:sid withName:name withReturnName:returnName isCircular:isCircular withOperatorID:idOperator withCompanyID:companyID withVersion:version];
        latestLineOpID = idOperator;
        [currentLine setCicID:cicID];
        [currentLine setOperatorID:operatorID];
        lineWithOwnStops = (idOperator == suboperatorid);
        itemcount++;
        progress = itemcount/totalItems;
        updateaction(progress);
    }
```

The XML File data is like this:

```
<Network CountiesNumber="0" ContactsNumber="2" LinesNumber="326" StopsNumber="3161" ZonesNumber="2866">
    <Zones>
        <OperatorZone Name="Cavadas (R 25 Abril, 60) Café O Renascer" Id="20274" />
    </Zones>
    <Stops>
        <Stop Id="108591" Name="Setúbal (Avª 22 Dezembro, 25)" CodName="2" IdZona="22793" CoordXX="-8.89310700" CoordYY="38.52755000" Observation="" />
    </Stops>
    <Lines>
        <Line ReturnLineName="Cacilhas - Cristo Rei" LineName="Cristo Rei - Cacilhas" IsCircular="false" CompanyId="101" IdOperator="84" Id="16344" Version="05-08-2019 00:00:00">
            <StopLines>
                <StopLine StopName="0" OrderPath_I="1" OrderPath_V="0" ZoneId="20435" Id="56356194" IdStop="109346" />
                <StopLine StopName="0" OrderPath_I="2" OrderPath_V="0" ZoneId="20423" Id="56356195" IdStop="109838" />
            </StopLines>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</Network>
```

EDIT - Example Database Method:

```
+ (Stop *)createStop:(int)id withName:(NSString*)name withCodName:(NSString *)codName
withIdZona:(int)idZona
withIdDistrito:(int)idDistrito
withIdConcelho:(int)idConcelho
withIdFreguesia:(int)idFreguesia
withLatitude:(double)latitude
withLongitude:(double)longitude
withObservations:(NSString *)observations
withOperatorZone:(OperatorZone *)operator
{
    Stop * stop = [Stop MR_createEntity];
    stop.ownStop = false;
    stop.name = name;
    stop.codName = codName;
    stop.idZona = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idZona];
    stop.idDistrito = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idDistrito];
    stop.idConcelho = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idConcelho];
    stop.idFreguesia = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idFreguesia];
    stop.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id];
    stop.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude];
    stop.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude];

    if (idDistrito != 0){
        NSLog(@"bla bla bla");
    }
    stop.distrito = [Distrito MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:idDistrito]];
    stop.concelho = [Concelho MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:idConcelho]];
    stop.freguesia = [Freguesia MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:idFreguesia]];

    stop.operatorzone = operator;
    //ac    [[stop managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    //    NSLog(@"Stop %d - %@ saved", [stop.id intValue], stop.name);
    return stop;
}
```

Theres also an example of a parser that this most likely looks as mine:
https://gist.github.com/xslim/1020767

Difference is, that hes using `NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` and I'm using `MR_createEntity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. So I decided to go with a pre-loaded DB instead of filling the data of my database from a local xml file.

Basically what I done was:

- After running the app with the local xml file, I let it create the BD then went to the ~Library/Developer/... to get the generated DB files, I had 3 files, but If I opened them with a program called DB Browser for SQLite the 3 files merged into 1 single file.
- After that I grabbed the only 1 single DB File, and then moved it into the desired Target of my project. Lets say I called it MyDB.sqlite

And then in my AppDelegate file after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I added this code:

```
// This code is needed to preload the database

NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentPath = [paths lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [documentPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.sqlite"];

// Check if the database already exists in the document folder, if it doesn't exist add it to the documents folder
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
    NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDB" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    NSError* err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Unable to copy preloaded database.");
    }
}

// Setup Magical Record in the document path
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL:storeURL];
```

For some reason the `setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed` wasen't working for me (Maybe because was getting the MyDB.sqlite files from the other targets? I don't know), so I decided to go with `setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL`

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want your app to start as fast as it can - don't do the work it needs on startup. Either do it before (at build time) or postpone it and do in background as much as you can.

In this particular example I'd recommend to run that code during the app build to convert XML to sqlite/CoreData, and ship your pre-populated database as a resource in the app bundle.

Note: it is possible to make a macOS tool to do that, and then use that tool for your app target as a Build Phase.

If you want to speed up the updates from the server, try to do the processing in the background. Use profiling tools to see what is the slowest part. During bulk imports into SQL often one of the slowest part is related to updating indexes. Instead of updating an index for each new row, sometimes it is possible to disable them, insert everything, and then build indexes from scratch. That can be much faster, but that requires deeper knowledge of how CoreData uses indexes. Sometimes the slowest part is related to searching. Instead of using the database search one could build a dictionary in memory and use it for faster searching.

Comment: So you mean If I convert the NSData into an NSDictionary and iterate that dictionary is faster than using the NSXML PARSE ? But won't be pratically the same since i need to use coredata to create new records on the database ?

Comment: Not saying that. For the XML update the first step is to measure the slowest part. You say "takes at least 2 minutes to read and store the provided data." How much time it takes to "read"? How much time it takes to "parse"? How much time it takes to "store"? Measure!

Comment: My main point is that for the initial run you don't even need this XML: pre-build the database, and ship it in the app.

Comment: The problem is that this app uses alot of targets (about 20), so i don't know how to do that, but do you have a tutorial or a guide on how to "_ship your pre-populated database as a resource in the app bundle_"

Comment: The first step is to make a macOS command-line tool that takes your XML and produces a CoreData database. Does it seem viable for you?

Comment: But my problem is, the database is made in run-time, so if I make a tool that creates that database I need to change my code, and the code I use to update the database from the server to recreate that database, I'm sorry but I'm not understanding how to do this without any guide

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. This is the general direction. I can't give you all the details, because your question is too broad at this point. I'd start by making a new macOS command-line app project with CoreData support, copying some code there form your app, and then see where it leads you (what parts are missing etc.)

Comment: From what I saw on a post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351493/using-an-existing-sqlite-database-in-magicalrecord

I already have on my target my DB and did the code has the guy in the awsner has done, the problem is when I'm trying to fetch the data, it has nothing.

But the DB I put on the folder has data on it.

Comment: Sounds like you have found your way to start, but have more questions on the way. Feel free to ask more on SO, and make sure to demonstrate the code! :)